# C#: How do I get the value of an unbound DataGridView cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm fairly newbie at C#.  I've seen questions answering how to set values in an unbound grid.  Which seems to work. But, to get the value back out doesn't seem to.  I did try searching for the answer.

I have an unbound DataGridView, named analogGrid.  Data is stored in an external class RTUdata.  It is a very simple grid, first column is read only with the row number.  Second value is a value the user can change which should store it back into RTUdata.  Loading the data into the grid seems to work fine with this method:

```
private void loadAnalog()
{
    analogGrid.RowCount = RTUdata.getAnalogCount(RTUdata.getRTUaddr());
    for (UInt16 i = 0; i < RTUdata.getAnalogCount(RTUdata.getRTUaddr()); i++)
    {
        analogGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].ValueType = typeof(System.UInt16);
        analogGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
        analogGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].ValueType = typeof(System.Int32);
        analogGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = RTUdata.getAnalogValue(RTUdata.getRTUaddr(), i);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite certain which event I should hook into as far as when to grab the value that the user entered and put it back into RTUdata.  But, I'm guessing it would be CellValidated(). So, I have this code:

```
private void analogGrid_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 1)
        return;

    Int32 value = (Int32)binaryGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    RTUdata.setAnalogValue(RTUdata.getRTUaddr(), e.RowIndex, value);        
}
```

But, on the line

```
Int32 value = (Int32)binaryGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
```

I get a runtime error of "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'"  As far as I can tell, "Value" should be Int32, I set the value type when I load the grid. So, why isn't the cast valid?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that the value being read from the cell is integer?  Perhaps its string and you need to convert it to integer, rather than casting it.

Comment: (FACEPALM)  I actually did try getting the string this way:  "binaryGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToString()" Which didn't give me what I needed. But I didn't try "...Value.Tostring()".  That is the issue.  I guess I figured the cell type should still be an UInt32 since I assigned that as the type.

Comment: No worries.  I'm sure I've done worse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to cast a string value to int, which won't work.  Instead, convert it with `.ToString()`.

Try this:

```
Int32 value = Int32.Parse(binaryGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I accepted your answer. Though, actually, don't you need to use Parse() rather than just assign it to an Int32 value?

Comment: Yes - I don't know what I was thinking!  I'll make that correction, and thank you for calling my attention to it!